# What do you call the signal at a crosswalk?

Tags: single-word-requests

When talking about crosswalks, we generally say they are lit (lighted if you prefer) or unlit when they have a traffic signal on them in America. However, traffic signal seems to me like a general term that may be applied to any sort of signal on the road. The flashing amber lights on some school speed limits, construction warnings, road closings, stoplights, etc. are all traffic signals.

Is there a specific term for the type of traffic signal used at crosswalks?
For example,

> I was going to cross the street but the */blank/* turned red, warning me not to cross.
>
> Many people, especially those in big cities, ignore */blank/* and cross the road when they want to.

Are there terms for the other types of signals I listed?

Comment: Crossing light...

Comment: To older generations it's the *walk/wait* light generally, where the *wait* light turns on to tell you not to walk.  However, "WAIT" (vs "DON'T WALK") hasn't been used on new pedestrian signals for 30 years, and most instances of "WALK" were replaced with the walking icon (and "DON'T WALK" with the hand signalling "stop") 10-20 years ago.  So now I suppose it's just a *pedestrian signal*.

Comment: And if a traffic cop catches you crossing against the light, I guess you're caught red-handed.

Comment: @HotLicks, would you submit your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To older generations it's the *walk/wait* light generally, where the *wait* light turns on to tell you not to walk. However, "WAIT" (vs "DON'T WALK") hasn't been used on new pedestrian signals for 30 years, and most instances of "WALK" were replaced with the walking icon (and "DON'T WALK" with the hand signalling "stop") 10-20 years ago. So now I suppose it's just a *pedestrian signal*.  (How boring.)

Comment: I think you're a bit off with the times.  In NY City, at least, "wait" signs were long gone at least 40 or 50 years ago.  It also seems that the hand signs began appearing more like 30 years ago, though I am not as sure of that.

Comment: @phoog - Well, it takes time for all that new fancy stuff to make its way to the hinterlands.

Answer (score 7):

These are know as *pedestrian crossing signals* or just *pedestrian signals*.  You may go [here](http://www.safeny.ny.gov/dot-ped.htm) to find the types that the state of New York uses.  If you have an extra $150 or so, you may buy one of your own on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Collectible-Traffic-Lights-Signals/95147/bn_3051666/i.html), where you'll find that they're also called *Walk/Don't Walk signs*.

Comment: But that sounds so pedestrian.

Comment: The NYS website does not include the one that counts down the number of seconds you have left to cross the street.

Comment: And if you happen to be visiting the UK, a country with very busy roads, these are the different crossings mentioned in [The Highway Code](http://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/rules-for-pedestrians---crossings-18-to-30.html)

Answer (score 2):

By all rights, it is a traffic light. One can say pedestrian traffic light if there's a need to differentiate, though this is moving farther away from the one-word search.

Going on the information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light), there is no single word to describe or refer to this specific light.

> Traffic lights, also known as traffic signals, traffic lamps, traffic semaphore, signal lights, stop lights, and (in technical parlance) traffic control signals,[1] are signalling devices positioned at road intersections, pedestrian crossings, and other locations to control conflicting flows of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***crosswalk signal***.

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22crosswalk+signal%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=D6vRVsasH8nbaoTTrfAD)